# How to avoid locking key-guard in windows-mobile

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-mobile, mobile

Can any one please help me, How to avoid key-guard lock programmatically in windows mobile.
i have an application in that after certain minutes  key-guard gets lock. i don't want mobile to get locked when my application is running. please suggest me how to do programmatically..

Thanks
Grabit

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which windows mobile you have but this works on mine.

Try this value in the registry HKLM\Security\Policies\Policies\00001023

Set it to 1 instead of 0. This will turn off locking

Comment: Hi Shiraz Bhaiji,

Thanks for the reply, i m not getting what you are telling,
But my problem is diffrent.
I have a form, i will launch that in my windows mobile Device and will keep my mobile idle for some time,then the device gets locked(key guard locked), i dont want device to gets locked when my application is running, so how to do it programmaticaly.

Comment: You could use this tool http://www.ghisler.com/ce.htm to change the values in the registry. This will stop the phone from locking. Not sure how you stop it for a limited period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found the solution for my problem here it is,
[**Suspend Killer Demo**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/SuspendKiller.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to press a virtual "key" every so often:

keybd_event(VK_F24, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

This will be ignored by applications and it will keep your device from timing out / suspending.

L.B.